# dart, regex, how not to allow special characters?

Tags: regex, dart

how not to allow special characters ? what I`ve tried is

```
final RegExp regex2 = RegExp(r"!^[`~!@#$%^&*()-_=]+$");
```

this seems not working and

```
final RegExp regex = RegExp(r"^[a-z0-9]+$");
```

I do not want this method too. This is because I have to allow not only English, but other languages as well.

Comment: 1. The `^` has to go inside inside the `[]` otherwise it means start of the strung. 2. The `-` has a special meaning inside `[]` so if you want match (or exclude) it literally, it has so go last

Comment: What is your definition of "special characters"?  The first regular expression accepts *only* those punctuation symbols.  If you want to *reject* those characters instead, you need to use `[^...]` instead.  But even if you fix that, that would not disallow, say, `[`, `]`, `<`, `>`, and many, many Unicode characters (including emojis).  IMO you need to reconsider and explain *why* you need to reject "special" characters.

Comment: @jamesdlin Hi I just want users to set their name without special characters inside app. I mean I think in my case of definition, if they are not putting normal usual languages "English,French,Arabic etc.." then it would be speicial characters in my case

Comment: Use for example `RegExp(r"^[\p{L} '-]+$", unicode: true).hasMatch(input)`. It will return true if the input string contains only letters, spaces, apostrophes or dashes.

Comment: @MikeM Thank you my freind I think it works! and suddenly got some curious things, how to add numbers on this? if you have to find that newly you do not have to answer I just appreciate your efforts I am impressed

Comment: See the posted answer, or add `\d` to the character set `[]` if you just want to add the digits 0-9, for example `r"^[\p{L} '\-\d]+$"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to allow *letters* and *digits*, but not just ASCII ones, you can use Unicode escapes:

```dart
var re = RegExp(r"^[\p{Letter}\p{Number}]+$", unicode: true);
```

or the shorthand:

```dart
var re = RegExp(r"^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$", unicode: true);
```

Trying to list all the non-letters is going to be extremely hard.
Trying to list all the letters is going to be equally hard.

In practice, you probably want to allow combining marks as well, so maybe something like "é" can be matched both as a combined character and as `e` followed by a combining accent:

```dart
var re = RegExp(r"^(?:\p{L}\p{Mn}*|\p{N})+$", unicode: true);
```

which also accepts the string `"ide\u0301"` (containing the `e`+accent combining mark for `é`).

Whether that is sufficient depends on what your actual use case is.
If it's trying to recognize people's actual names, you probably need more characters. Some names contain dashes or apostrophes too, like
"Mary-Jane O'Reily".
(Also, there are some pretty funky `\p{Letter}`s out there).

Comment: I just tried this .. and it seems not workring

Comment: @MikeM Really?? Does it return true when the input value is given as 'abc'? I get false all the time. and I am currently using Flutter 2.02 so the Dart version is not going to be a ploblem I guess

Comment: Sry so many good explanations but still don\`t understand clearly . To sum it up, languages ​​of all countries in the world are allowed, but is it correct that other special characters are returned as false?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the `unicode: true` flag to the constructor. Fixing it.

Comment: The RegExps here will recognize what the Unicode specification considers *letters* followed by *non-spacing marks* (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm), or *numbers*.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property for more information.
Whether that actually matches what you want depends on precisely what you want.